# Polynomials non-negative on the integers

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $P$ be a real polynomial of exact degree $2n$ ($n \geq 1$) whose zeros are real numbers and such that 
\begin{equation*}
P(j) \geq 0 
\quad \text{for any} \quad 
j \in \mathbb{Z}. 
\end{equation*}
Does there exist non-negative real numbers $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n,$ with at least one of the $\alpha_i$ non-zero, such that the polynomial 
\begin{equation*}
Q(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \alpha_k P(x+k)
\end{equation*}
is non-negative on the whole real line, i.e.; $Q(x) \geq 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

I would like to add that this question is not merely a mathematical curiosity but pops up naturally while working on spectral transformations of discrete measures.

Comment: Yes, this follows from continuity (so $P$ has a minimum) and the fact that $P(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$.

Comment: Some interesting observations: if $Q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\alpha_kP(x+k)$ then it isn't true  (for example  $(x-2)(x-1)(x-1)(x)(x)(x+1)(x+1)(x+2)$ does not ave this property for that definition of Q. However it appears to be true for your definition of Q since your polynomial (ofcourse) has 2n roots and you  seem to need at least 2n+2 roots

Comment: Zen. Yes, I believe that you need to go for 0 to at least n to achieve the non-negativity of Q. Your example is a good one.

Comment: Corbennick. Thanks for trying to solve the problem. But could you please read the problem carefully. Already the example of zen shows that the question is not that easy to answer.

Comment: I feel that @Corbennick is right. Indeed, $\ Q(x) := P(x)+P(x+d)\ $ will satisfy $\ \forall_{x\in\mathbb R}\ Q(x)\ge 0\ $ whenever constant $\ |d|\ $ is large enough.

Comment: Wlod AA. You cannot use P(x+d) with |d| large enough. You can only use P(x+d) with d smaller than n. The sum in Q is from 0 to n. Your solution Q does not answer the question of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! Indeed, I have overlooked the restriction on $k$ inside the expression for $Q$ (in $P(x+k)$). ***************** This illustrates the principle of presenting mathematics in two parallel ways, both formally through symbolic expressions, and descriptively, through a plain text--each of the methods by itself leads to misunderstandings. ******* I meant to propagate this principle of double presentation also on MO except that etc.

Comment: @WlodAA: I don't see how one can misunderstand this question which is well formulated (except for the missing implicit condition that at least one of the $\alpha_i$ should be nonzero).  Also, I do not understand the downvote, the question looks reasonable and difficult to me.

Comment: @PeterMueller, I was the very first one to upvote this question. Your insinuation is unnecessary, like all insinuations. *** About the ability of anyone (including me) to misunderstand, I admire how great you are and your ability to absorb and understand texts, congratulations to you.

Comment: @Peter Muller: Thanks for mentioning that I should add that at least one of the $\alpha_{i}$ should be nonzero.

Comment: The good news is that it looks loke there exists a universal (independent of $P$) sequence $\alpha_k={n\choose k}^2$ with this property. The bad news is that I can prove it only for $n=1$ (trivial) and $n=2$ (a bit less trivial).

Comment: @fedja: Many thanks for your comment. I believe the same thing as you. In fact, the coefficients $\alpha_{k}$ that you find are the coefficients for which $Q$ is a square of a polynomial when the zeros of $P$ are consecutive integers. This is one of the reasons I believe that using discrete Taylor formula could solve the problem. Unfortunately, I am still not able to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: If $\alpha_k$ are fixed, we may without loss of generality suppose that our polynomial has roots at $0,\dots,2k-1$ and $n-k$ pairs of double zeroes. If it helps anyhow.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You comment can be very helpful. Would it be possible to explain how you reduced the problem to your family of polynomials ? I do believe, as fedja does, that the coefficients  $\alpha_{k}$ are fixed, i.e; $\alpha_{k} = \binom{n}{k}^2$.

Comment: by studying the extreme rays of the cone of polynomials which are non-negative at integer points

Comment: This condition is not essential even a priori. Again, if coefficients are fixed.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: you seem to have forgotten some extreme rays, for example $X(X-1)(X-3)(X-4)$. The extreme rays of the cone are the polynomials with $2n$ integer roots (counting multiplicities).

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle ah, of course you are correct. This should make checking fedja's conjecture for small $n$ routine.

Comment: (indeed, any linear multiple $x-a$ for $a\in [n,n+1]$ is a convex combination of such products for $x-n$, $x-n-1$, this immediately yields Mikael de la Salle's claim)

Comment: To prove the full claim, one also have deal with degree $2$ irreducible factors.  But this is not a problem: such a factor $x^2+bx+c $ satisfies $b^2 <4c $, and so is an average of $x^2\pm 2\sqrt c x +c$.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle also, such a factor is a sum of a positive constant and $(x+b/2)^2$

Comment: Does there exist a Fundamental Theorem for expressing real polynomials on $\ \mathbb Z\ $ as Products of $\ \binom x {a_k}\ $ multiplied by a polynomial of constant sign, where $\ a_k\in\mathbb Z\ $ for $\ k=1\ldots n\ $ ? ****** This would perhaps imply a positive answer to the ***Question***.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Actually the extremal points are slightly different: they are polynomials with $2n$ distinct integer roots that go in pairs with the difference $1$ in each pair. Still, I do not see how to use it. On the other hand, I have a computer assisted proof that we are fine for $n\le 5$ but this proof breaks down for $n=7$ for sure. The good news is that it doesn't use the non-negativity of $P$ on all integers, so there is no counterexample yet.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle Be careful: you cannot have the result for *all* polynomials with $2n$ roots. Fortunately, you do not need to. I posted the correct description of the extremal points in my response to Fedor Petrov :-)

Comment: @fedja I think, Mikael did not claim that all such polynomials are extreme, but only that all extreme polynomials are such. Indeed, we may additionally assume that the roots are distinct by using $x^2=\frac12(x(x-1)+x(x+1))$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Well, formally you are right, of course, but if you want the statement about the extremal polynomials to be useful, you'd better make sure that there is some hope to get the desired result for the entire class you introduce. What I provided is the exact description but, of course, it looks too rigid at the moment and a meaningful relaxation is, probably, due. I just wanted to emphasize that one cannot relax the class to consider too much :-).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Occasionally I wish somebody could give me a good whack on the head to keep my brains running and the older I get, the more frequently I need it. The problem is actually trivial.

I will prefer to think that $P$ is non-negative on some disjoint with integers arithmetic progression $\Lambda$ with step $1$ . Then we need to show that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}^2 P(k)\ge 0\,.
$$
Let $\lambda$ be a number such that $\Lambda=\{x:\cos(\pi x+\lambda)=0\}$ and put $Q(x)=x(x-1)\dots(x-n)$. Consider the meromorphic function 
$$
F(z)=\frac{\tan(\pi z+\lambda)-\tan\lambda}{Q(z)^2}P(z)\,.
$$
Note that the poles of $F$ are simple and $F(z)$ decays like $|z|^{-2}$ on big circles between the poles of the tangent, so the sum of the residues converges to $0$.
Now the residue at the zero $k$ of $Q$ is $\frac{\pi}{(n!)^2\cos^2\lambda}{n\choose k}^2P(k)$ while the residues at the poles $x\in\Lambda$ of the tangent are $-\frac 1{\pi Q(x)^2}P(x)\le 0$. The end.

Comment: Trivial. :-) ${} $

Comment: @fedja: what do you mean by "disjoint with integers arithmetic progression with step 1" Is for example  $\Lambda = \{1,2,6,7,8,10,11\}$ valid ? or just a single arithmetic progression of step 1 ?

Comment: @RachidAit-Haddou I mean some translation of $\mathbb Z$ that does not coincide with $\mathbb Z$ itself. In other words, I replace the original $P$ by $P(\cdot+x)$ in your notation

Comment: The interesting part is how did you come up with this identity: $\sum_{k} \binom{n}{k}^{2}P(k) =\frac{(n!)^{2} \cos^{2}\lambda}{\pi^{2}} \sum_{x \in \Lambda}\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)^{2}}$

Comment: @PaataIvanisvili The interesting part is actually why after teaching graduate complex analysis for the whole semester I didn't see it immediately :lol: It is clear (from the general duality mumbo-jumbo) that if the linear combination in question is, indeed, positive, then some identity like that must exist. Next, all such identities come from the residue theorem, so I need a function with poles at $\Lambda$ and extra poles at $0,\dots,n$ that is decaying at infinity faster than $P$ grows. I certainly know how to place poles with residues of the same sign at $\Lambda$ (continued)

Comment: That is what tangent is for. Extra poles and the decay dictate $Q^2$ in the denominator. Thus, I already get $\frac{\tan(\pi z+\lambda)}{Q(z)^2}P(z)$ forced upon me. Now, the second order poles are definitely not what I want. So that has to be corrected by offsetting the numerator by $\tan\lambda$ to make it vanish to the first order at integers. Then all that remains is to compute the residues.

Comment: Beautiful proof and nice explanation

Comment: Long ago I used to see few problems bit more trivial than this.

Comment: @FedorPetrov That's what bothers me most in our profession: with age we lose the grasp of techniques that should be at our fingertips. The widely believed "experience replacing ingenuity" claim is just a total nonsense: if the brain deteriorates in one respect, it deteriorates in every other one as well. The only thing we acquire with age is the ability to deceive ourselves into thinking that proving some triviality is still a success just because we spend on it way more time than we should. I completely agree with Hardy that (with a few exceptions) after 40 we are largely out of business.

Comment: @fedja: This is my first participation in MO and do not really know how it work. I want to use your result above in a manuscript I am writing. I will, of course, attribute the result to you. But may be you want to expand on the idea of the question and write your own paper. This way I can just refer to your work (continued)

Comment: @fedja: By expanding on the idea, I mean the generalization of the question to the multivariate setting. There is of course an obvious generalization from your result above. However, I believe that in the multivariate setting we can do better by translating in each direction by less than $n$. It is probably a difficult problem.

Comment: @RachidAit-Haddou The way it works with me is that you can use my posts in whatever way you wish. When online, I either share information and opinions with no strings attached, or do not share them at all. It would be nice though to mention MO in your paper in some way (they depend on an external funding at least partially, so any documented success story is welcome)..:-)

Comment: @fedja : The older brain may be in possession of certain *combinations of facts* that the younger brain was not, and may therefore have an advantage, even if the younger brain *would have* done a better job if it had had the same facts at its disposal. By the way, Deligne agrees with you that he was stronger when he was 30, but he does say that he does have one advantage over his younger self: better technique. http://www.ams.org/notices/201402/rnoti-p177.pdf

Comment: @RachidAit-Haddou See https://mathoverflow.net/help/licensing for the license.